# Logout from Azure AD using using own app

Tags: java, authentication, web-applications, active-directory, azure-web-app-service

we've used [1] do start working on our own Application that uses Azure to Authenticate Users. So far this works like a charm, but we would also love to have a "Logout" after some research we have this link [2] as logout - the user is brought to a page where it says he has been logged out. But actually isn't and is still able to access the  restricted area. This is also the case when the cache is cleared, which we don't even want to be a necessary step.

[1] https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/tree/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal4jsample

[2] https://login.windows.net/##tenant_id##/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/adal4jsample

@tenant_id we tried both the actual ID aswell as the name. Localhost is currently configured as target url in Azure.

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

kind regards
Michael

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Using a logout controller to invalidate the session did the trick.